# How can I change gridview when I click imageview

Tags: android, gridview

I want to change view array when I click each 'image view'
when i click no.1 'imageview' load 1 column grid view
click no.2'image'-> 2 columns grid view no.3 'imageview'->3 columns grid view

I made xml file each grid view. how can I make it?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView menu1,menu2,menu3;
GridView first,second,third;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    menu1 = (ImageView) findViewById(Nemo1);
    menu2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Nemo2);
    menu3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Nemo3);

    first = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid1);
    second = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid2);
    third = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid3);

    menu1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            first.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    menu2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            second.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    menu3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
              third.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Suggest to use Recyclerview

Comment: Use RecyclerView and manage columns count in runtime, so u shouldn't manage visibility and have different gridviews at all. Or just use `gridView.setNumColumns()` method

Answer (score 0):

•   MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
private ImageView menu1,menu2,menu3;
private RecyclerView recycler;
private GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager;
private ArrayList<String> list;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    menu1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Nemo1);
    menu2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Nemo2);
    menu3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Nemo3);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++){
        list.add("item " +i);
    }
    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
    recycler.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
    menu1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 1);
            recycler.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        }
    });
    menu2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 2);
            recycler.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        }
    });
    menu3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, 3);
            recycler.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
        }
    });
}
}
```

•   RecyclerAdapter.java

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends      RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> list;
public RecyclerAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> list) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.list = list;
}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemTextView.setText(list.get(position));
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView itemTextView;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView);
    }
}
}
```

•   item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="item1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

•   activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="pithiyasagar.gridviewcolumn.MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lnrImageButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Nemo1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Nemo2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Nemo3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lnrImageButton">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

•   Output Screen:

[image]

[image]